# There was trouble creating the ESLint CLIEngine

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint, npx, prettier-eslint

```
There was trouble creating the ESLint CLIEngine. -
 'basePath' should be an absolute path
```

Trying to use eslint

```
$ npx prettier-eslint **/*.js
```

but getting:

```
prettier-eslint [ERROR]: There was trouble creating the ESLint CLIEngine.
prettier-eslint-cli [ERROR]: There was an error formatting "test/fizzBuzz.test.js":
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 'basePath' should be an absolute path.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This is due to an issue with selecting the files with

`**/*.js`

A current UNIX workaround: use `$PWD`, i.e.

```
$ npx prettier-eslint $PWD/'**/*.js'
```

This produced correct files as output

re: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint-cli/issues/208

This also applies to similar issues using `package.json`

for instance having

```
"lint": "eslint . && prettier-eslint --list-different **/*.js",
"format": "prettier-eslint --write **/*.js"
```

will also generate that error.
On Unix this can currently be fixed with `$PWD`

```
"lint": "eslint . && prettier-eslint --list-different $PWD/'**/*.js'",
//                                                    /|\
"format": "prettier-eslint --write $PWD/'**/*.js'"
//                                 /|\
```